# The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
var questions = [
    {
    "questionText":"Who created fb?", 
    "answers":["Mark Zukerberg","Bill Gates","Sundar Pichai","None"]
    },
    {
    "questionText":"What is 5+4?", 
    "answers":["9","12","1","13"]
    },
    {
    "questionText":"Who is me?", 
    "answers":["Bishal","subha","biplob","rahul"]
    }
  ];
```

```dart
var _questionIndex = 0;
print(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']);
```

it is giving the above error

Comment: Not reproducible, it prints "Who created fb?".

Comment: You probably used the same tutorial as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068179/map-key-is-a-string-but-returns-object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code works well. However try this and let me know the result:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
    {
    "questionText":"Who created fb?", 
    "answers":["Mark Zukerberg","Bill Gates","Sundar Pichai","None"]
    },
    {
    "questionText":"What is 5+4?", 
    "answers":["9","12","1","13"]
    },
    {
    "questionText":"Who is me?", 
    "answers":["Bishal","subha","biplob","rahul"]
    }
  ];
  
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  print(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']);
```

Comment: Idk why but ur one works...even when i put dynamic instead of var it works. But still confused why var dont work

Comment: I am not sure, but defining variables format specifically usually works better. However, please let me know if you found the reason.